# How to change from foreach to display all data at once?

Tags: c#, wpf

currently, I've used `foreach`

now, I don't want the looping. I want all the data to show at once. it's like a list. for example, I have 3 rows of data and I want it to show all the data at once without looping. How can I do that?

Comment: `have 3 rows of data and I want it to show all the data at once without looping.` doesn't make any sense as there is no context, its not clear, and its completely unclear what you re asking. if possible try to add more relevant information (to the question)

Comment: @raynaqarla: Why wouldn't the data be showed "at once" if you use a foreach loop to populate the list?

Comment: @mm8 for example in `itemIds` there are 3 `id` so by using the code I do above it will display 3 rows of data. what I want is all the 3 `id` and its data display in 1 row (listbox) instead of 3

Comment: @raynaqarla: Please clarify *how* you want to display them on the screen then.

Answer (score 0):

You could put it in a temporary list first, then use `.AddRange` to add it to your main list all at once.

```
List<int> itemIds = itemRelationBO.GetItemRelationItem(item.ItemId);

List<ItemRelationDisplay> temp = new List<ItemRelationDisplay>();

foreach (var id in itemIds)
{
    ItemRelation itemRelation = new ItemRelation();
    ItemRelationDisplay itemRelationDisplay = new ItemRelationDisplay();
    itemRelationDisplay.ItemIdSub = id;
    itemRelationDisplay.ItemNameSub = itemRelation.ItemNameSub;
    itemRelationDisplay.ItemQuantitySub = 1;
    temp.Add(itemRelationDisplay);
}

itemRelationList.AddRange(temp)
```

Comment: I've try your code but I've got this error `cannot convert from 'tfWindowsWPF.EntityModel.ItemRelationDisplay' to 'tfWindowsWPF.EntityModel.ItemRelation' 
`

Comment: Sorry, `temp` should have been `List<ItemRelationDisplay>`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: okay now there's no error but still the data display in 3 different row

Answer (score 0):

```
if (item.IsMainItem == true)
{
     ItemDisplay itemDisplay = new ItemDisplay();
     itemDisplay.ItemCode = item.ItemCode;
     itemDisplay.ItemName = item.ItemName;
     itemDisplay.ItemPrice = simpleItem.ItemPrice;
     itemDisplay.Quantity = 1;
     itemDisplayList.Add(itemDisplay);
     ItemRelationBO itemRelationBO = new ItemRelationBO();
     List<int> itemIds = itemRelationBO.GetItemRelationItem(item.ItemId);
     itemRelationList.AddRange(itemIds.Select(id =>
     {
           ItemRelation itemRelation = new ItemRelation();
           return new ItemRelationDisplay
           {
                 ItemIdSub = id,
                 ItemNameSub = itemRelation.ItemNameSub,
                 ItemQuantitySub = 1
           };
      }));
}
```

Comment: I've try your solution but my datagrid is empty when I run the code. Do you have any idea what's the problem ?

Comment: did you have a list before?

Comment: it might be because your list had some valies and I was setting its items not adding to them, check the answer now.

Comment: yes. I've updated my question with full code. I have 2 list to display

Comment: Sir, I got this error `cannot convert from 'tfWindowsWPF.EntityModel.ItemDisplay' to 'tfWindowsWPF.EntityModel.ItemRelationDisplay` at `result.Add(itemDisplay);` since the `itemDisplay` and `ItemRelationDisplay` is two different things