# How to merge the output from foreach loop into one?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, foreach, binding

**Code** is like the main item while **IdSub** is like the sub item for the main. 1 main item may have several sub item.

I have this foreach code at my code behind.

```
 foreach (var subID in Ids)
     {
          Display display = new Display();

           display.Code = item.Code;
           display.Name = item.Name;
           display.Price = item.Price;
           display.IdSub = subID ;
           DisplayList.Add(display);
    }
```

Since **Ids** have 3 **subID** so the output have 3 row of data. What I want is since the **Code**, **Name** , **Price** is the same its like main item. I want it to merged into 1 row with several **IdSub**. How can I combine/ merges this data ?

Comment: This question is basically exactly the same as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55565332/how-to-change-from-foreach-to-display-all-data-at-once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you need to change `IdSub` field/property on your `Display` class to array of integers: `int[]` (you can do it differently, but it's best approach IMO).

Then you can omit the loop:

```
Display display = new Display()
{
  Code = item.Code,
  Name = item.Name,
  Price = item.Price,
  IdSub = Ids //if Ids is array of ints, else you need to use ToArray() method
}

DisplayList.Add(display);
```

To display data of `IdSub` with binding, you need to define additional property on your `Display` class:

```
public string IdSubDisplay
{
  get
  {
    return string.Join(",", IdSub);
  }
  set { }
}
```

and bind to `IdSubDisplay`.

Comment: its give an error for `Ids` since `Ids` is a list like this `List<int> Ids =...`

Comment: @newbie Then define `IdSub` as `List<int>` or write `IdSub = Ids.ToArray()`

Comment: sir I've try your approach now there is no error but my output for Id Sub become like this `Int32[] Array` where goes wrong ? it didn't display the id sub

Comment: @newbie How do you display it? You should use `string.Join` method to display all elements in collection: `string.Join(",", display.IdSub);`

Comment: I used `Binding` like this `<ListBoxItem Content="{Binding IdSub}"/>` where should I put the string. join ?

Comment: Thank you so much. You save my life :)

Answer (score 0):

You have several options to do that. Here is one of the simplest:

```
foreach (var id in itemIds)
{
    if (DisplayList.Any(x=> x.Code == item.Code && x.Name == item.Name && x.Price == item.Price))
    {
        var display = DisplayList.Single(x=> x.Code == item.Code && x.Name == item.Name && x.Price == item.Price);
        display.IdSubs.Add(id);//change IdSub to IdSub, as a list of its previous type
    }
    else
    {
        Display display = new Display();
        display.Code = item.Code;
        display.Name = item.Name;
        display.Price = item.Price;
        display.IdSubs = new List<int>();//Assumed that IdSub was int
        DisplayList.Add(display);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a few error using this approach. since inside my `itemIds` only contain `id` it does not contain anything else beside that.

Comment: the `itemIds` look like this ` List<int> itemIds =...`

Comment: I've made an edit in if statement, check it, please.

Comment: I have error here `new List<int>();` it said `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>' to 'int'`

Comment: and here `display.IdSubs.Add(id);` it said `'int' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no accessible extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: change `IdSub` to `IdSubs`, as a list of its previous type. If `IdSub` was `int`, `IdSubs` will be `List<int>`

Comment: if I change it there will be an error said something like `display does not contains IdSubs`

Comment: create a new property in `Display` class named `IdSubs` with type `List<int>`.